# Crypto++ equivalent to PHP mcrypt_encrypt MCRYPT_3DES/MCRYPT_MODE_CBC

Tags: php, c++, crypto++, 3des

I have the following PHP code to encrypt a text using a key:

```php
function des_ed3_crypt($msg, $key) {
   $bytes = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
   $iv=implode(array_map('chr', $bytes));

   return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $msg, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
```

And my corresponding C++ function, using Crypto++ is:

```cxx
std::string des_ed3_crypt(std::string const& msg, std::string const& key)
{
    unsigned char iv[8] = { 0 }; // 0-filled

    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::DES_EDE3>::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(key.c_str()),
                   key.size(), iv);

    std::string ret;

    CryptoPP::StringSource(msg, true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter
                 (e, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ret)));

    return ret;
}
```

But they don't return the same encrypted text. I want the change the C++ code to make equivalent to the PHP code, and not the opposite.

For the following key and message:

```php
$key = "keykeykeykeykeykeykeykey";
$msg = $key;
```

The PHP code returns a cyphertext of 24 bytes (base64 encoded as):

```
a78URfI6EV8m3sTaDDDrntI8VbjWHiwm
```

But C++ returns a cyphertext of 32 bytes, but with a matching prefix of 24-bytes (base64 encoded as):

```
a78URfI6EV8m3sTaDDDrntI8VbjWHiwm9M15+pzUnuM=
```

So, there's some extra bytes in the C++ version which I don't know where do they come from. I think it can be related with the padding scheme, but I don't know the padding scheme used by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, it was the padding. The PHP `mcrypt_crypto` function applies a zero-padding, so, I only have to specify to `cryptopp` that I want to apply a zero-padding to the encryption:

```
std::string des_ed3_crypt(std::string const& msg, std::string const& key)
{
    unsigned char iv[8] = { 0 }; // 0-filled

    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::DES_EDE3>::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(key.c_str()),
                   key.size(), iv);

    std::string ret;

    CryptoPP::StringSource(msg, true,
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter
            (e, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ret),
             CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme::ZEROS_PADDING));

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I hope you did not spend too long on it. It was asked and answered a few years ago at [Crypto++ and mcrypt](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/Jpv4sm-547o) on the mailing list. Is there any place we can put it to make it easier on mcrypt users>